# CSS The | didn't show up

Tags: html, css, web, inline, display

I am using CSS for the first time. I am just making a test website I just want to test my code to see if it works when the | didn't show up inbetween the About me and My Songs

[Image of what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MmPq.png)

There is suppose to be a | sort of line inbetween About Me and My Songs

The CSS

```
nav ul li {
display: inline;
border-right 2px solid #111111;
padding-right: 8px;
padding-left: 8px
```

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet1.css"/>
</head>
    <body>
        <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="about-me.html">About Me</a></li> 
            <li><a href="songs.html">My Songs</a></li>
        </ul>
                    <h1>I am a YouTuber!</h1>
        <p>This is my website check out other things about me above.</p>
            </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you share the snippet of HTML and CSS pertaining to that section?

Answer (score 1):

There is a colon missing in your `border-right` declaration.

It should be `border-right: 2px solid #111111;`